# Comparing array of char pointers to string

Tags: c++

I was wondering if and how one would compare an array of char pointers to a string.

So say I have this array of char pointers:

```
char *input[20];
```

And each index of input contained a string, for example, `input[0]` contained `hello`. What would I use if I needed to do a comparison to find a keyword contained within the `input` array?

Comment: You want to [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) an item in a container?

Comment: Unless your exercise or assignment requires you to use plain arrays and pointers, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the size of the array isn't known at compile-time) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Then it would be *very* easy to [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) a specific string in the array (or vector).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes for this assignment they handicapped us but I will keep that in mind for future reference thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you mean a `char**`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what your problem is here. But something like:

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
    if ( strcmp( input[i], "keyword" ) == 0 ) {
       // found - do something
    }
 }
```

But in C++ you would be better off using std::string and std::vector rather than messing around with C-style arrays and pointers.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, apologies for the vagueness. Thank you so much!